# Does Kafka support java 10 or java 11?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am planning to use kafka for stream and messaging purpose. Our infrastructure is moving to java 11. So wanted to know does kafka support java 10 or java 11 ?.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently Java 10 works ... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6855.  But the best strategy is to try it and see.

Comment: Here is what I got from kafka developer community https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7264

Answer (score 13):

From the Kafka tickets themselves:

- KAFKA-6855: This shows Kafka is now able to start with Java10.  That ticket is closed, and that shows versions 1.1.1 as 2.0.0 as the only ones that have the fix - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6855
- KAFKA-7264: These issues have been resolved as of 11/Oct/18, as of Kafka release 2.1.0 <s>This ticket shows there's still outstanding issues to get Kafka running under Java 11.  This ticket is targeted for 2.1.0 release, so it's definitely still an open issue</s> - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7264

Answer (score 5):

The issues mentioned in KAFKA-7264 have been resolved as of 11/Oct/18. And it worked fine when I tried it in a VM with Ubuntu 18.04, OpenJDK 11 and Kafka 2.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! This would've been a fantastic edit of the other answer, instead of a separate one.

Comment: Good point, I wanted to make a comment actually but didn't have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads), version 2.1.0, released on 2018-11-20, supports Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

**Dec 2021**

Here is page in documentation about Java support for latest release **3.0** at the time of writing this:

**https://kafka.apache.org/30/documentation.html#java**

In similar way you can find Java related page for any other release in the future - just change **/30** to whatever version you want.